# If "x" runs a distance of "m" metres in a triangular path of side 30,25,35. How many times he have ran through 1 side?

Tags: python-3.x

A person running a distance of , say 560m in a triangular path of sides 30,25 and 35m. How can I find the number of times he has ran through a single side say from 30m side?

```
ran = int(input("Dist. ran: "))
a = 30
b = 25
c = 35
r = ran
while r == 0:
```

I'm not able to come up  with an idea...

Comment: 30+25+35=90, so every 90m they run through all the sides 1 time (90 divided by 90). 560/90 is about 6.2, so that's 6 times plus a little bit down one of the sides, depending where they start

Comment: that said, this is an arithmetic question and probably not really appropriate for this site

Comment: @SashaKondrashov Thank you for your solution. And as you said , if it's inappropriate, I'll delete it in a moment

Comment: No worries, you don't have to delete it necessarily, I just wanted to let you know because it will likely be closed. And you're welcome!